# Computing mean of filtering and smoothing distributions from a particle filter

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, state-space-models, particle-filter, sequential-monte-carlo

Suppose I have a model with latent states $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_T$ and observations $y_1, y_2, \ldots y_T$. I run a sequential monte carlo algorithm to give me the following approximation to $p(x_{1:T} | y_{1:T})$:

$$p(x_{1:T} | y_{1:T}) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n W_T^i \delta_{X_{1:T}^i}(x_{1:T}),  $$

where $X_{1:T}^i$ is the ith particle trajectory sampled, and $W_T^i$ is the corresponding importance weight. I'm slightly confused on how I can get from this approximation of the joint posterior, to an approximation of the filtering and smoothing distributions for each time step $t$:

$$p(x_t | y_{1:t}), \\p(x_t | y_{1:T}).$$

In particular, the tutorials that I'm going through (see [here](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Edoucet/doucet_johansen_tutorialPF2011.pdf)) only seem to describe how to approximate $p(x_{1:T} | y_{1:T})$, and don't really talk about how to recover the filtering/smoothing distributions from that approximation.

Comment: Algorithmically they’re just ignoring components of the sample paths. It’s justified asymptotically for any sampling algorithm—not just particle filtering. The mean of the filtering distribution, say, can be written as an expectation with respect to the joint density of the whole path. They’re the same thing, so whatever converges to one converges to another.